# Haskell: How to define my custom math data type recursively (stop infinite recursion)

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I'm defining a custom data type to help me with my calculus for a project. I have defined this data type as follows:

```
data Math a =       
            Add (Math a) (Math a)
        |   Mult (Math a) (Math a)
        |   Cos (Math a)
        |   Sin (Math a)
        |   Log (Math a)
        |   Exp (Math a)
        |   Const a
        |   Var Char

    deriving Show
```

I am creating a function called `eval` that partially evaluates a mathematical expression for me. This is what I have:

```
eval (Const a) = (Const a)
eval (Var a) = (Var a)

eval (Add (Const a) (Const b)) = eval (Const (a+b))
eval (Add (Var a) b) = eval (Add (Var a) (eval b))
eval (Add a (Var b)) = eval (Add (eval a) (Var b))
eval (Add a b) = eval (Add (eval a) (eval b))

eval (Mult (Const a) (Const b)) = (Const (a*b))
eval (Mult a (Var b)) = (Mult (eval a) (Var b))
eval (Mult (Var a) b) = (Mult (Var a) (eval b))
eval (Mult a b) = eval (Mult (eval a) (eval b))

eval (Cos (Const a)) = (Const (cos(a)))
eval (Cos (Var a)) = (Cos (Var a))
eval (Cos a) = eval (Cos (eval a))

eval (Sin (Const a)) = (Const (sin(a)))
eval (Sin (Var a)) = (Sin (Var a))
eval (Sin a) = eval (Sin (eval a))

eval (Log (Const a)) = (Const (log(a)))
eval (Log (Var a)) = (Log (Var a))
eval (Log a) = eval (Log (eval a))

eval (Exp (Const a)) = (Const (exp(a)))
eval (Exp (Var a)) = (Exp (Var a))
```

This works fine for the most part. For instance, `eval (Mult ((Const 4)) (Add (Cos (Const (0))) (Log (Const 1))))` results in `(Const 4.0)`

My problem arises whenever I have a variable added with two constants:
`eval (Add (Const 4) (Add (Const 4) (Var 'x')))` gives me infinite recursion. I have determined that the issue is because I call `eval` on `eval (Add a b) = eval (Add (eval a) (eval b))`. If I make this line, `eval (Add a b) = (Add (eval a) (eval b))`, I stop the infinite recursion, but I am no longer simplifying my answers: `Add (Const 4.0) (Add (Const 4.0) (Var 'x'))` results in the exact same `Add (Const 4.0) (Add (Const 4.0) (Var 'x'))`. How do I get something like `Add (Const 8.0) (Var 'x')` instead?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you don't treat expressions that are already simplified any differently than those that aren't. You keep calling `eval` until both operands are constants and if that never happens, you never terminate. The most simple problematic input would be `Add (Var "x") (Const 5)`. Such an input should end the recursion and just return itself. But instead it will keep calling `eval` on the same input:

```
  eval (Add (Var "x") (Const 5))
= eval (Add (Var "x") (eval (Const 5)))
= eval (Add (Var "x") (Const 5))
= eval (Add (Var "x") (eval (Const 5)))
= ... ad infinitum
```

In general the way to avoid this kind of problem in the first place, i.e. to make it obvious when you're missing a base case, is to structure your function in such a way that all recursive cases of your function call itself only with sub-expressions of the argument expression.

In this case that could be achieved by evaluating the operands first and then constant-folding the result without another recursive call. That would look like this:

```
eval (Add a b) =
  case (eval a, eval b) of
    (Const x, Const y) => Const (x+y)
    (x, y) => Add x y
```

Here the only recursive calls are `eval a` and `eval b` where `a` and `b` are subexpressions of the original expression. This guarantees termination because if all cases follow this rule, you'll eventually reach expressions that have no subexpressions, meaning the recursion must terminate.

Comment: I've implemented it
and it's simplifying somewhat but not entirely. For instance, `eval (Add (Const 10.0) (Add (Add (Const 4.0) (Var 'y')) (Var 'x')))` only gives `Add (Const 10.0) (Add (Add (Const 4.0) (Var 'y')) (Var 'x'))`

Comment: @JackBuckley That's more complicated. One way to achieve that would be to turn a sequence of additions into a list and than replace all constants with a single one. Note that this simplification (unlike what we did so far) is operator specific. For, say, the power operator `2^(3^x)` would already be the most simple form and could not be simplified any further. The only reason that we can simplify `2+(3+x)` to `5+x` is that we know that addition is an associative operation.

Comment: @JackBuckley Also note that there are many more optimizations that one could apply (`1*x == x+0 == x`, `0*x = 0`, `2*x + 3*x == 5*x` etc.). It's just a matter of how many rules about the operators you can think of and how much time you want to spend implementing them.